# Extension only works when Chrome starts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am testing my Chrome extension by using the following codes:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "login_popup.html"}, function(tab){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({oid: tab.openerTabId});
});
```

However, a new tab was created only when Chrome started, but no tabs were created when I opened open a new page. Shouldn't the `chrome.tabs.create` be executed whenever a new page is loaded?

The `manifest.json` is:

```
{
   "name": "minus_test",
   "version": "1.0",
   "background_page": "minus_test.html",
   "permissions": [ "*://*/", "tabs" ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `background_page` gets executed once when Chrome starts at which point it creates a new tab. If  you want to create a new tab ever time a new window is opened you need to use the [chrome.windows.onCreated](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#event-onCreated) listener.